# generate main.xml inside onCreate()

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to generate a main.xml inside onCreate()? Such as:

```
package avm.project;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;


public class AVMOrderSystemActivity extends Activity { 
      ViewFlipper flipper;


      @Override 
      public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) { 
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        //File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        /*for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                Log.i("XML Generator","File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
            } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
                Log.i("XML Generator","Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
            }
        }*/
        String xml="";
        xml=xml+"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n";

        xml=xml+"<RelativeLayout xmlns:android=\"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android\"\n"+
                "android:layout_width=\"fill_parent\" android:layout_height=\"wrap_content\"\n"+
                "android:orientation=\"horizontal\" android:padding= \"5px\">\n";
        xml=xml+"<ViewFlipper android:id=\"@+id/adflipper\"\n"+
                "android:inAnimation=\"@android:anim/fade_in\" android:outAnimation=\"@android:anim/slide_out_right\"\n"+
                "android:paddingLeft=\"15px\" android:layout_width=\"fill_parent\"\n"+
                "android:layout_height=\"fill_parent\" android:autoStart=\"true\"\n"+
                "android:flipInterval=\"5000\">";

        Resources a=this.getResources();
        try
        {
            for (int i=0x7f020000 ;i<0x7f020020;i++)
            {
                String name=a.getResourceName(i);
                xml=xml+"<ImageView android:layout_width=\"fill_parent\" android:src=\"@"+name.substring(name.indexOf(':')+1)+"\"\n"+
                    "android:layout_height=\"fill_parent\"></ImageView>\n";
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.i("resoruces","exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        xml=xml+"</ViewFlipper>\n</RelativeLayout>";
        xml=xml+"<!--xxx-->";


        try{
            // Create file 
            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("res/layout/main.xml");
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
            out.write(xml);
            //Close the output stream
            out.close();
        }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
            Log.i("xml write","exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.main); 

        flipper=(ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.adflipper); 
        Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.restbutton);


        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
          public void onClick(View view) { 
            flipper.showNext();
          } 
        }); 
      } 
    }
```

I have implemented the code and it can get the project drawables to generate a main.xml accordingly but its not working (I got an exception: file not found res/layout/main.xml). (My aim is to generate main.xml according to varying number of png images) What am I doing wrong, Is it possible to get over this or Is there any other solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Wow. Incredible code but totally the wrong approach. Add the views dynamically!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the src of your ImageView dynamically without having to generate the XML.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.your_image_view);
imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_png));
```

And you can add more by creating them dynamically and adding them to the parent RelativeLayout:

```
for (int i=0x7f020000 ;i<0x7f020020;i++)
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_png_reference);
    RelativeLayout ll = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_relative_layout_id);
    ll.addView(imageView);
}
```

Comment: Not quite the full answer. OP needs to add views dynamically, i.e. a variable number of ImageView.

Comment: Thanks guys I kinda get the idea. I guess I need to thread this thing and change the image with time interval. However animations will be a problem.